# How to convert a SQL subquery to a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have two tables with a 1:n relationship: "content" and "versioned-content-data" (for example, an article entity and all the versions created of that article). I would like to create a view that displays the top version of each "content".

I use this query (with a simple subquery):

```
SELECT 
   t1.id, 
   t1.title, 
   t1.contenttext,
   t1.fk_idothertable
   t1.version
FROM mytable as t1
WHERE (version = (
        SELECT MAX(version) AS topversion
        FROM mytable
        WHERE (fk_idothertable = t1.fk_idothertable)))
```

The subquery is to the same table that extracts the highest version of a specific item. The versioned items will have the same fk_idothertable.

In SQL Server I tried to create an indexed view of this query but subqueries are not allowed in indexed views.

What is a way to convert this query to one with JOINs?

It seems like indexed views cannot contain:

- subqueries
- common table expressions
- derived tables
- HAVING clauses

Comment: btw... fk_idothertable is the foreign key to the master table

Comment: Can you get an explain on this so we can see where the actual problem is?

Comment: Loosely related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733660/select-most-recent-states-from-history-table

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This probably won't help if table is already in production but the right way to model this is to make version = 0 the permanent version and always increment the version of OLDER material. So when you insert a new version you would say:

```
UPDATE thetable SET version = version + 1 WHERE id = :id
INSERT INTO thetable (id, version, title, ...) VALUES (:id, 0, :title, ...)
```

Then this query would just be

```
SELECT id, title, ... FROM thetable WHERE version = 0
```

No subqueries, no MAX aggregation. You always know what the current version is. You never have to select max(version) in order to insert the new record.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT
  t2.id,
  t2.title,
  t2.contenttext,
  t2.fk_idothertable,
  t2.version
FROM mytable t1, mytable t2
WHERE t1.fk_idothertable == t2.fk_idothertable
GROUP BY t2.fk_idothertable, t2.version
HAVING t2.version=MAX(t1.version)
```

Just a wild guess...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I really liked the elegance of your solution but when I execute it I get:

Column 'mytable.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Just add all the fields in SELECT to GROUP BY - AFAIK the standard needs it, but there are DBMSs that don't require it.

Comment: If I do this, whenever the title changes between versions this item (with the same fk_idothertable) will apper twice in the results (different title + different version)

Comment: No, the extra lines you're talking about will be killed by the HAVING clause. [I assume dependency (idother..., version)=>id => contenttext]

Comment: Damn it! Indexed views in SQL Server cannot contain HAVING clauses either :-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient this would be, but:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.version
FROM mytable AS t1
    JOIN (
        SElECT mytable.fk_idothertable, MAX(mytable.version) AS version
        FROM mytable
    ) t2 ON t1.fk_idothertable = t2.fk_idothertable
```

Comment: But still... even with a GROUP BY this query basically returns all the list items from mytable + the max version of each item. It does not just return the items with the highest version.

Answer (score 0):

You Might be able to make the MAX a table alias that does group by.

It might look something like this:

```
SELECT 
   t1.id, 
   t1.title, 
   t1.contenttext,
   t1.fk_idothertable
   t1.version
FROM mytable as t1 JOIN
   (SELECT fk_idothertable, MAX(version) AS topversion
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY fk_idothertable) as t2
ON t1.version = t2.topversion
```

Answer (score 0):

I think FerranB was close but didn't quite have the grouping right:

```
with
latest_versions as (
   select 
      max(version) as latest_version,
      fk_idothertable
   from 
      mytable
   group by 
      fk_idothertable
)
select
  t1.id, 
  t1.title, 
  t1.contenttext,
  t1.fk_idothertable,
  t1.version
from 
   mytable as t1
   join latest_versions on (t1.version = latest_versions.latest_version 
      and t1.fk_idothertable = latest_versions.fk_idothertable);
```

M

Comment: Thanks Mark. This query does return the correct results but since it uses a "common table expression" is not valid for me in order to create an indexed view in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server accepts a LIMIT clause:

```
SELECT 
   t1.id, 
   t1.title, 
   t1.contenttext,
   t1.fk_idothertable
   t1.version
FROM mytable as t1
ORDER BY t1.version
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

(DESC for descending sort.)

LIMIT 1 chooses only the first row and
a DBMS usually does good optimization.

Answer (score -2):

Like this...I assume that the 'mytable' in the subquery was a different actual table...so I called it mytable2.  If it was the same table then this will still work, but then I imagine that fk_idothertable will just be 'id'.

```
SELECT 
   t1.id, 
   t1.title, 
   t1.contenttext,
   t1.fk_idothertable
   t1.version
FROM mytable as t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Version) AS topversion,fk_idothertable FROM mytable2 GROUP BY fk_idothertable) t2
        ON t1.id = t2.fk_idothertable AND t1.version = t2.topversion
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The subquery is actually a query to the same table that extracts the highest version of a specific item. Notice that the same versioned items will have the same fk_idothertable.