# Select Most Recent States From History Table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have inherited a table with a structure something like this:

```
ID   Name   Timestamp   Data
----------------------------
1    A      40          ...
2    A      30          ...
3    A      20          ...
4    B      40          ...
5    B      20          ...
6    C      30          ...
7    C      20          ...
8    C      10          ...
```

`ID` is an identity field and the primary key and there are non-unique indexes on the `Name` and `Timestamp` fields.

What is the most efficient way to get the most recent record for each item name, i.e. in the table above rows **1**,**4** and **6** should be returned as they are the most up-to-date entries for items **A**,**B** and **C** respectively.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 (onwards):

```
WITH MostRecentRows AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, Data,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM MySchema.MyTable
) 
SELECT * FROM MostRecentRows 
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Huh. +1. I got this to work, but I couldn't tell you whether `MostRecentRows`, `Row_Number()`, or `PARTITION` is doing the magic.

Comment: Excellent approach. That was useful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming there are no duplicate timestamps per name, something like this should work:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Timestamp, Data
FROM test AS o
WHERE o.Timestamp = (SELECT MAX(Timestamp)
                     FROM test as i
                     WHERE i.name = o.name)
```

Comment: Yes, this would only work if there are no duplicate timestamps.  The CTE description is definately safer since it will only return one row.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT
  ID, Name, Timestamp, Data
FROM
  DataTable
  INNER JOIN
  (
     SELECT ID, MAX(Timestamp) Timestamp FROM DataTable GROUP BY ID
  ) latest ON 
    DataTable.ID = Latest.ID AND 
    DataTable.Timestamp = Latest.Timestamp
```

Comment: This could return more than one record if there are multiple records for one time stamp.

Comment: I am perfectly aware of this fact. An additional outer GROUP BY clause migrates this risk, should duplicate timestamps be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005/2008, then the CTE solution already listed by Mitch Weat is the best from a performance perspective.  However, if you are using SQL Server 2000, then you can't assume there aren't duplicate Name | TimeStamp combinations.  Use the following code to return only one record per name:

```
SELECT ID
    , Name
    , TimeStamp
    , Data
FROM DataTable dt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Name
    , MIN(DataTable.ID) AS MinimumID
FROM DataTable  
INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT Name
        , MAX(Timestamp) AS Timestamp 
    FROM DataTable 
    GROUP BY Name) latest 
    ON DataTable.Name = Latest.Name
    AND DataTable.Timestamp = Latest.Timestamp
GROUP BY Name) MinimumLatest
ON dt.ID = MinimumLatest.ID
```

So if you add another record like 9 C 30, then this will only return ID 6.  If you don't go this far, then you may end up return 9 C 30 and 6 C 30.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way :

```
SELECT ID,Name,Timestamp, Data
FROM   Test_Most_Recent
WHERE Timestamp = (SELECT MAX(Timestamp)
                 FROM Test_Most_Recent
                 group by Name);
```