# Using SELECT within SELECT in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

It is common to use `SELECT` within `SELECT` to reduce the number of queries; but as I examined this leads to slow query (which is obviously harmful for mysql performance). I had a simple query as

```
SELECT something
 FROM posts
 WHERE id IN (
  SELECT tag_map.id
  FROM tag_map
  INNER JOIN tags
  ON tags.tag_id=tag_map.tag_id
  WHERE tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5', 'tag6')
  )
```

This leads to slow queries of "query time 3-4s; lock time about 0.000090s; with about 200 rows examined".

If I split the `SELECT` queries, each of them will be quite fast; but this will increase the number of queries which is not good at high concurrency.

Is it the usual situation, or something is wrong with my coding?

Comment: `SELECT` within `SELECT`?! This is just like that movie... Inselection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In MySQL, doing a subquery like this is a "correlated query". This means that the results of the outer `SELECT` depend on the result of the inner `SELECT`. The outcome is that your inner query is executed once per row, which is very slow.

You should refactor this query; whether you join twice or use two queries is mostly irrelevant. Joining twice would give you:

```
SELECT something
FROM posts
INNER JOIN tag_map ON tag_map.id = posts.id
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id
WHERE tags.tag IN ('tag1', ...)
```

For more information, see the MySQL manual on [converting subqueries to JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rewriting-subqueries.html).

Tip: `EXPLAIN SELECT` will show you how the optimizer plans on handling your query. If you see `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` you should refactor, these are mega-slow.

Answer (score 2):

You could improve it by using the following:

```
SELECT something
FROM posts
INNER JOIN tag_map ON tag_map.id = posts.id
INNER JOIN tags
ON tags.tag_id=tag_map.tag_id
WHERE <tablename>.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5', 'tag6')
```

Just make sure you only select what you need and do not use *; also state in which table you have the tag column so you can substitute **<tablename>**

Comment: This is what we call **JOIN**.

Comment: yup, inner join twice, at least i think its faster than the in clause

Answer (score 1):

Join does filtering of results. First join will keep results having 1st ON condition satisfied and then 2nd condition gives final result on 2nd ON condition.

```
SELECT something
FROM posts
INNER JOIN tag_map ON tag_map.id = posts.id
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id AND tags.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5', 'tag6');
```

You can see these discussions on stack overflow :

[question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/)
[question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600943/)

Join helps to decrease time complexity and increases stability of server.

Information for converting sub queries to joins:

[link1](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/6.0_Subquery_Optimization_Cheatsheet)
[link2](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/429-how-to-convert-subqueries-to-joins/)
[link3](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0140__Table-Joins/ConvertsubqueriestoJOINs.htm)