# Oracle SQL inner select doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with my pl/sql statement.

This is the good working select statement:

```
SELECT P.DAYS FROM PLPLANPEAKPROGRAM P WHERE P.ID = 1060;
```

Returns; 1,2,3 (varchar2)

The main sql is here:

```
SELECT * 
from FIFLIGHTS   
LEFT JOIN PLPLANPEAKPROGRAMCOPY ON FIFLIGHTS.IATACODE = PLPLANPEAKPROGRAMCOPY.STATIONCODE   
WHERE  TO_CHAR(FIFLIGHTS.SCHEDULEDTIME, 'D') IN (SELECT  P.DAYS 
                                                 FROM PLPLANPEAKPROGRAM P 
                                                 WHERE P.ID = 1060) ;
```

But this doesn't return any result.

Also this above is returned well;

```
SELECT * 
from FIFLIGHTS   
LEFT JOIN PLPLANPEAKPROGRAMCOPY ON FIFLIGHTS.IATACODE = LPLANPEAKPROGRAMCOPY.STATIONCODE   
WHERE TO_CHAR(FIFLIGHTS.SCHEDULEDTIME, 'D') IN (1,2,3);
```

What's problem and solution, please help ?

Comment: also what it this ` TO_CHAR(FIFLIGHTS.SCHEDULEDTIME, 'D') `?

Comment: this is for filtering days that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that:

```
SELECT P.DAYS
FROM PLPLANPEAKPROGRAM P
WHERE P.ID = 1060;
```

Returns `1,2,3`.  That means that it returns a single string value.  Not a list with three elements.  The `to_char()` function call returns single values, such as `1` or `2`.  There are no commas, so these cannot match.

This is a bad data format.  You should be storing the list with one element per row.  SQL offers a very powerful way to store lists, called tables.  That said, you can solve this problem with `exists`:

```
SELECT *
from FIFLIGHTS LEFT JOIN
     PLPLANPEAKPROGRAMCOPY
     ON FIFLIGHTS.IATACODE = PLPLANPEAKPROGRAMCOPY.STATIONCODE
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM PLPLANPEAKPROGRAM P
              WHERE P.ID = 1060 and
                    P.DAYS LIKE '%' || TO_CHAR(FIFLIGHTS.SCHEDULEDTIME, 'D') || '%'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from FIFLIGHTS LEFT JOIN 
PLPLANPEAKPROGRAMCOPY ON FIFLIGHTS.IATACODE = PLPLANPEAKPROGRAMCOPY.STATIONCODE
WHERE TO_CHAR(FIFLIGHTS.SCHEDULEDTIME, 'D') 
IN (SELECT P.DAYS FROM PLPLANPEAKPROGRAM P WHERE P.ID = '1060') ;
```

add single quote to your argument `'1060'`

Comment: @volkan no im sorry, can you give me the 3 columns you are using in `PLPLANPEAKPROGRAM `

Comment: @volkan or you can try to check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585592/using-select-within-select-in-mysql-query

Comment: Sure STATIONCODE, DEPARTMENTNAME, DAYS are columns in PLPLANPEAKPROGRAM